# get Segmentation fault in GMock API GetValueAndDelete()

Tags: c++, googlemock

I get a strange issue when use gmock, a thread gets a Segmentation fault in `GetValueAndDelete()`, check gmock code, this function is simple:

```
template <>
class ActionResultHolder<void> : public UntypedActionResultHolderBase {
 public:
  void GetValueAndDelete() const { delete this; }
......
```

How it will Segmentation fault?

```
stack info
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000049c0da in testing::internal::ActionResultHolder<void>::GetValueAndDelete() const ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000049c0da in testing::internal::ActionResultHolder<void>::GetValueAndDelete() const ()
#1  0x000000000049c194 in TestServerPolicyMock::start_accept(std::error_code&) ()
```

Comment: Your post is not nearly complete enough to give an answer but I would suggest looking to make sure the object has not already been deleted. Or maybe it was allocated on the stack in which case deleting it is never valid.

Answer (score 0):

As SoronelHaetir mentioned your post is not accurate enough to give an answer, so I will try to give you some possible solutions.

The problem you are facing when using GMock may arise for several reasons :

- The object GMock is trying to access has been already deleted or destroyed, in that case it may throw a segmentation fault.
- As you mention there is a specific thread throwing this segmentation fault , another reason may be that when trying to use GMock and GDB, it can be the case that **GDB** itself is **not able to find the suitable libraries** when trying to launch several **threads**,  arising the next message at startup:

  ```
  warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available.
  ```

  If this is the case, try to use the following commands to set the sysroot or to help gdb find the proper libraries : **"*set solib-search-path*"** or **"*set sysroot*"**. Do this **before** trying addresing the **command bt**.
- In my case, using a **void() return method** has made me suffer a little bit when trying to integrate it with GMock , specifically when compiled for **ARM**. When setting expectations for methods returning void() segmentation faults were always thrown, just as is it your case. 
  However, I don't really know why and I thought it should have been reported somewhere , **when changing the return type** to bool (or any other type) **everything worked out for me**.